# Redirect to HTTPS when using multiple domains and pass throughs

Tags: http, https, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config, http-redirect

I am using Unix. I am using NGINX.  I am, running 3 websites on the same server using 3 different domains.  Each website is running on a different port number and I using 3 separate pass through settings to server each site. Each site has SSL enabled.

This all works well.

I want to redirect any http requests to https for all the sites. I have tried many samples but none seem to work.

I have been focused on getting just 1 site redirected.

I have used this configuration:

```
 server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name website1;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

But nginx returns this error:

> 2022/11/01 19:05:58 [emerg] 493911#493911: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed
> (98: Address already in use) 2022/11/01 19:05:58 [emerg]
> 493911#493911: still could not bind()

I have looked through all the config files and I cannot see port 80 being used anywhere.

This is my config serving all 3 sites@

```
map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
  default upgrade;
  ''      close;
}

upstream websocketAdmin {
  server 127.0.0.1:7771;
}

server {
     server_name  website1;
     location / {
     error_page 503 = /blank.html;
     error_page 502 = /blank.html;
     error_page 404 /blank.html;
     error_page 500 502 503 504 /blank.html;     
     proxy_http_version 1.1;
     proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
     proxy_set_header   Connection keep-alive;
     proxy_set_header   Host $host;
     proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
     proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
     proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
     proxy_read_timeout 86400s;
     proxy_send_timeout 86400s;
     client_max_body_size 2M;
     proxy_pass     https://websocketAdmin;
     } 
     
     
    add_header Last-Modified $date_gmt;
    add_header Cache-Control 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate, max-age=0';
    if_modified_since off;
    expires off;
    etag off;

    location /BaseDiagnosticsHub {
    proxy_pass     https://websocketAdmin;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

    location = /blank.html {
        root /var/www/html/ErrorPages;
    }


   listen 443 ssl;  
   ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/website1_ssl
   ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/website1_ssl/privkey.pem;  
}

upstream websocketCloud {
  server 127.0.0.1:9771;
}

 
server {
     server_name  website2;
     location / {
     error_page 503 = /blank.html;
     error_page 502 = /blank.html;
     error_page 404 /blank.html;
     error_page 500 502 503 504 /blank.html;     
     proxy_http_version 1.1;
     proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
     proxy_set_header   Connection keep-alive;
     proxy_set_header   Host $host;
     proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
     proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
     proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
     proxy_read_timeout 86400s;
     proxy_send_timeout 86400s;
     client_max_body_size 2M;
     proxy_pass     https://websocketCloud;
    }    

     location /media {
        alias /var/www/media/;
    }
     
    add_header Last-Modified $date_gmt;
    add_header Cache-Control 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate, max-age=0';
    if_modified_since off;
    expires off;
    etag off;

    location /BaseUserHub { 
        proxy_pass     https://websocketCloud;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
     }

    location = /blank.html {
        root /var/www/html/ErrorPages;
    }

    listen 443 ssl; 
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/website1/fullchain.pem;  
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/website1/privkey.pem;  
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;  
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;  
}



upstream websocketHome {
  server 127.0.0.1:5001;
}
 

server {
     server_name  website3;
     location / {
     error_page 503 = /blank.html;
     error_page 502 = /blank.html;
     error_page 404 /blank.html;
     error_page 500 502 503 504 /blank.html;     
     proxy_http_version 1.1;
     proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
     proxy_set_header   Connection keep-alive;
     proxy_set_header   Host $host;
     proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
     proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
     proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
     proxy_read_timeout 86400s;
     proxy_send_timeout 86400s;
     client_max_body_size 2M;
     proxy_pass     https://websocketHome;
    }
     
     location /downloads {
         alias /var/www/downloads/;
    }
     
    add_header Last-Modified $date_gmt;
    add_header Cache-Control 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate, max-age=0';
    if_modified_since off;
    expires off;
    etag off;    

    location = /blank.html {
        root /var/www/html/ErrorPages;
    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/website3/fullchain.pem;  
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/website3/privkey.pem;  
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; 
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;  
}
```

Comment: If your nginx fails to bind port 80, that means that another process has already taken port 80. Try `sudo netstat -nap | grep LISTEN | grep tcp | grep ':80 '`

Comment: Thanks @DusanBajic. yes I realise that.  Running netstat tells me that www.realisemotion.cloud is running on port 80. If I stop that service then port 80 is released.  If I restart then it is taken up again. So, the issue is what is in my config file (above) that is taking up port 80?  (nb port 80 is not being used anywhere in theat web app)

Comment: If you want to use nginx on port 80, you need to uninstall/disable that Realisemotion service (or reconfigure it to use another port)

Comment: you missed the point of my question.  I am trying to redirect all http to https.  How would I do that please?

Comment: In order to do that, you first need to enable nginx to use port 80.